# Transfer WP users Automatically

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a domain + web hosting site. for that, I have to create a support ticket system on another domain.  I want to automatically register/add users to my support website whenever a customer register on my domain hosting site. can I use "cron jobs" for that. and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store your SQL password on your local profile:

   ~/.my.cnf

   [client]

   user = root

   password = yourpassword
2. Create SQL script getuser.sql

Get user_login, user_email, display_name (and password hash if needed) from table wp_user to your ticket system user table.
Get your client email from wp_options admin_email (also wp_x_options on multisite).

3. Run the sql using cron

   mysql -h "server-name" "database-name" < "getuser.sql"

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use WordPress API support. There is actually a plug in if your not well versed with writing you own connection. https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/